# To plot branch cut of logarithm

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I like to see the branch cut of the function:

$$1 - z \ln[(1+z)/z].$$

If I plot it in the complex plane:

```
Plot3D[Re[1 - (x + I y) Log[(1 + x + I y)/(x + I y)]], {x, -2, 
2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

The result is:

[image]

which shows the brach cut correctly between -1 and 0. How can I get rid of the hole in the picture and have a smooth line as a branch cut rather than a white line discontinuity?

Also the same for contour plot:

```
With[{z = x + I y}, 
ContourPlot[Re[1 - z Log[(1 + z)/(z)]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
Contours -> 40]]
```

[image]

Comment: Add the plot option: PlotRange -> All

Comment: @Fraccalo Many thanks! Can we have a smooth line for the brach cut rather than "white line" discontinuity?

Comment: Not sure, but if you have an analytical formula of where the branch cut is, then it would be quite simple to plot it on top of the original 3d plot

Comment: You can use `Exclusions -> None` to get rid of the white line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change "Rainbow" with any ColorScheme you prefer, and the rescaling values {-2,1} to obtain different scaling.

```
With[{z = x + I y}, 
 ContourPlot[Re[1 - z Log[(1 + z)/(z)]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> Range[-4, 2, .1], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {-2, 1}]] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All]]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can also use the new (as of Version 12) `ComplexPlot` function, too:

```
ComplexPlot[1 - z Log[(1 + z)/z], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, Mesh -> 10, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Re[#2] &, Im[#2] &}]
```

[image: A complex plot.]

Or the 3D version:

```
ComplexPlot3D[1 - z Log[(1 + z)/z], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
   Mesh -> 10, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: 3D complex plot.]